# Displaying 3D routes in Google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2, google-earth-plugin

I want user to be able to enter source/destination and take a virtual tour of the route.
PHP is my preferred solution. I am not sure where to start from. I do not have much experience with Google map 3D APIs so need some pointers.

I need something that is similar to Google maps's Helicopter view feature. Gives a bird's eye tour of your route.

[image: I need to display a 3D route like this to the visitor]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use Javascript, which powers the [Google Earth API](https://developers.google.com/earth/)

Check out the examples at the code playground, especially how to [create a line string](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#creating_line_strings) (for your route) and how to [move the camera](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#move_camera)